# View which user deleted certain post?

Tags: wordpress

So I have this problem. A client has a wordpress website and the content is managed by 3 admins. One of them deleted all the content and no one will admit that he did it. So I need to investigate who deleted all the posts.

Is it possible to do in any way? I googled it and didn't find anything about something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Wordpress doesn't come with a user action log.  There is loads of plugins out there which can do it though.

Can you not get the posts back by running a recent backup in place? I know it doesn't solve the problem but as I don't think there is anyway to track it, may as well prevent it from happening again or something.

Comment: I honestly don't think you can track it, maybe look in the apache logs to see whether you can see what IP logged on at what time and track it that way... Unless its on the same network, then I doubt you'll be able to do much.